# Specify an extra option on render call by default on every index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I have a controller

```
class Api::V1::InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @invoices = Invoice.all

    render json: @invoices, each_serializer: Api::V1::InvoicePreviewSerializer 
  end
end
```

On every single controller i will be specify that the serializer used is the name spaced with 
`Api::V1::`

Then model name and then model name followed by `PreviewSerializer`

How could I on the appication controller specify that on every index action append `each_serializer: Api::V1::MODEL_NAMEPreviewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tested this but I think it should work like this:

```
# in the ApplicationController
def render(*args)
  if action_name == 'index'
    options = args.extract_options!
    options[:each_serializer] = Api::V1::InvoicePreviewSerializer
    args << options
  end

  super(*args)
end
```

Hope that works and helps!

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks!